# First Android project, as well as first using Mercurial, need to choose my IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans, mercurial

I finally have an idea for a project to learn Android with (more on that in another question soon), and enough time to actually work on it. I'm also using it as an opportunity to work on a project with version control and learn Mercurial to do it.

I've worked with Eclipse for the first year of university and am sort of used to it, pretty much just used it to write and compile my Java code. I tried NetBeans recently and find things much cleaner and a bit easier to work with, plus the built in Mercurial support is good to have.

The problem is the Android SDK is designed for Eclipse. Is there an easy way to use NetBeans for Android development with as many features as in the plugin for Eclipse? Would it be better just to stick to Eclipse and find a Mercurial plugin? (if so which one?)

What are the pros and cons of either choice? I want to be able to make an informed decision to make this learning experience as worthwhile as possible.

The only cons I see for either at the moment are the annoyance of plugin use in Eclipse (I learned about that when I tried to add C++ to Eclipse and just couldn't do it) and the fact that Android SDK is made for Eclpise use so it may not be optimal in NetBeans.

Maybe my assumptions are completely wrong, I would love for that to be the case since it just means more learning!

Comment: Is there anyway you could be pursaded to use git instead of Mercurial? As a college of mine at google once said "You don't choose to a bar because it's got the best or cheapest drinks, you choose a bar based on where your friends are". Most people these days who are doing distributed version controll are haning out at the git bar.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum, git my be the most popular bar, but what If you prefer to hang out at a private club?  If you are not working on an open source project, it doesn't make much difference.  I use both on a daily basis, they each have their own strengths.

Comment: @mikerobi Fair enough. Just thought it couldn't hurt to mention git.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum: That may be the worst reason for choosing a VCS I’ve ever heard. Mercurial has many advantages over Git (especially in terms of simplicity, user friendlyness and cross platform support), and although it is less popular it is far from marginal. Why do you feel this person must be ‘pursuaded’?

Comment: @LaurensHolst makes a good point. I'm curious as well. I initially chose Mercurial because I'm a Windows user but doing some searching around SO yesterday I discovered git seems to be fine on Windows.I've never really understood the difference between the two and between github and bitbucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of Eclipse either, but setting up an Android development environment in it couldn't be easier. Here's a good place to start:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

I originally wanted to develop for Android in Vim, but then thought that there's more than enough issues with learning Android, I might as well go traditional and make things as easy as possible on myself.

As for Mercurial, I find it's always better to run your version control system through the command line anyway. That way if you ever switch environments, you don't have to relearn it.

Comment: Mercurial integration for Eclipse: http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE

Answer (score 2):

If you have experience with Eclipse, use it.  I also have used (and prefer) NetBeans, but when I began Android development I switched back to Eclipse because it has the ADT plugin and full support for the Android toolchain.  I think if you go Netbeans you will end up in a constant hell of incompatibilities, missing functionality, and things being "not quite right."  The ADT plugin is easy to set up by following the tutorial on Google's Android dev site.

Another alternative you should consider is IntelliJ, which has full Android support.